# Audio Broadcaster for use in Airplanes

Tags: headphones, broadcast

I will be travelling at the end of the month.  I have hearing aids that are paired to the phone (Samsung Note 20). It gets uncomfortable with on the ear aids (with a cable and speaker inside the ear) and reading glasses, to then out on headphones on top.

I am wondering if there is something out there that could broadcast the airplanes Movie sounds to my phone which could be resent to my hearing aids.  I already have a mechanical  adaptor for the airline connector to jack.

A bonus would be that I could use the same tech to transmit the TV sound to my ear (on my hearing aids) late at night.

The closes thing I can find is  the AirFly SE.  It wont send it to the phone, so I still have to use the headphone.

[image]